# Gem Installation

Tags: rubygems

When I try to install gemcrack I get the below message

```
"Irb<main>:001:0> gem install crack
Name Error: undefined local variable or method ‘crack’ for main: Object
From <irb> :1
From C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in ‘<main>’ "
```

I am a new learner and am helpless about the same as I don't know any programming knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying this in irb. Exit from irb and then run the command "gem install crack" normally from cmd.